# How to provide 3D Touch quick actions inside iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, 3dtouch

If you were using Home app in iOS, you may have noticed that there's Quick Actions-like menu when you force touch on accessory. If device doesn't support 3D touch, then you do it with the long press. Here's two videos, first from iPhone 5, that doesn't support 3D Touch, and the second from iPhone 7 that does, https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDZKu.jpg, https://i.stack.imgur.com/qls5F.jpg

How to realize such functionality? What class can be used as a view for this? Should I write custom `UIView` subclass? There are a few similar questions, but they do not provide specific answer.

EDIT:

I do not mean how to create quick actions, I mean how to create actions view when I force touch `UICollectonViewCell`.

Any help wold be appreciated.

Comment: See: [Home screen actions](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/extensions/home-screen-actions/)

Comment: I edited question. I meant how to provide actions view on force touch on `UICollectionViewCell`